# Insert text in front of each Excel cell

Tags: excel, text, replace, excel-2010

I have an Excel 2010 worksheet with a column of numbers, e.g.

```
-1.5629E+00
-1.5745E+00
-1.4344E+00
-1.6456E+00
```

These are log10 values, and I want the original values:

```
0.027359
0.026638
0.036776
0.022614
```

Of course I could insert a column with the proper operation done, but that would upset subsequent use of the worksheet. I'd rather find a way to insert this text

=10^

in the beginning of each cell in the original column. I tried recording a macro, but that feature simply recording adding an entire new entry in the cell, not inserting text at the beginning.

Comment: By hand, you mean? I'd rather not ;)

Comment: Ahh, I see. Yes, that will work, and not too burdensome. But I may prefer the VBA code (with my suggested corrections) as in the long run it will be easier. Shame that MS doesn't provide more powerful search/replace in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Select your log10 values and run this:

```
Sub AntiLog()
    Dim c as Range
    For Each c in Selection.Cells
        If IsNumeric(c.value) then c.Value=10^c.Value
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Not picky. I corrected it and removed the test for greater than zero, but it won't show my edits until "peer reviewed".

Comment: Perhaps you can explain a bit on how this helps solve OP's issue?

Comment: @LaughDonor - OP has a column of log10 values which they would like to convert to the anti-log equivalent. Unless I completely mis-read the question this will perform that operation on any selected cells.  Do you disagree ?

Comment: No, but you just posted code. Future visitors may find it difficult to follow without some commentary. :) Which is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have misunderstood @pnuts's comment above. VBA seems like overkill here. Let's say your column of values is `A`. In column `B`, use the formula

```
=10^A1
```

and then apply that downward. Finally, copy that column and paste special as values over column `A` and then delete column `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I finally arrived at:

```
Sub AntiLog()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Selection.Cells
    If IsNumeric(c.Value) And Not IsEmpty(c.Value) Then c.Value = 10 ^ c.Value
Next c
End Sub
```

Associate with any key desired. Then, click on the entire column range, tap your key, and job done in place. More work initially but now it's a few-second process to fix these columns. Thanks to everybody who responded, and esp. Tim Williams; your code gave me enough to get the final job.